# How do I fix keyboard mapping problems in VirtualBox running Debian as a guest

Tags: virtualbox, debian, keyboard-layout

I've installed a bare-bones Debian Sid under VirtualBox on a Windows 7 laptop. I've done this so I have a handy Linux development box when I'll be on the road next month. However I'm having trouble getting the key mapping to work correctly. My (shift+2) " and @ (shift + ') and | (shift + ) keys don't work.

I've tried this under the console as well as withing a rxvt terminal under a window manager on the guest. I've run "dpkg-reconfigure keyboard configuration" and set my keyboard up as both 101 and 104 generic PC keyboards with GB key-mappings but they all exhibit the same broken behaviour.

According to showkeys:

```
Keycode 54 (shift) + 40 is @ (should be ")
Keycode 54 (shift) + 3 is " (should be @)
Keycode 54 (shift) + 43 is ~ (should be |)
```

So are the keycodes going from VirtualBox to the console wrong or has the keymaping failed to take on the guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously solved this 5 minutes after posting the question. It turned out the Windows 7 laptop had been configured for South Africa. Although this didn't affect the keys sent to notepad (which worked as I expected) it did mess up Virtual Box. Once I fixed the keyboard in Windows "Region and Language" everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019 I had this exact same issue with an Ubuntu VM.  Posting solution here for others:

Click launcher (which is 9 dots bottom left of screen).  Find the Settings app and start that.

Choose Region & Language.  To the right you can see a number of settings.  I had to choose a new Input Source.  I had chosen English (UK), but had to choose English (Au) to get things to work.

Note that you can see your keyboard layout with each new input source by selecting the input source and clicking the little keyboard icon to the lower right.